# Why is my included php file not showing in Dreamweaver CC?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using Dreamweaver CC to create html pages and I have a simple php file that looks like this:

```
 <html>

 <head>


 </head>
 <body>

   <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>

</nav>



 </body>
 </html>
```

In the body of my html page I'm doing this:

```
<?php include("menu.php");?>
```

I don't know if it matters but I working in Fluid Grid Layout.  Both of the files are in the same directory for simplicity.  For some reason the html of the php file is not being rendered.  I plan to style it with css later but when I view the page in the browser nothing shows.

What can I be doing wrong?

Thanks for any help with this one!

Comment: php is server side wont render without a server, dreamweaver is not a server

Comment: Your pages (both), should have .php extension, and you need server, as mentioned, to test .php pages. If you are windows user - check wamp: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: I'm using WAMPSERVER 2.5.  I've created an apache alias that points to the folder that contains the html file and the php file.  Sorry I didn't mention this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script might be throwing an exception beforehand. Can you figure out how far the script is getting?